# How do I right pad a timestamp field from Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

A typical timestamp in a select returns as `2023-02-28 16:20:25.123`.

Where the milliseconds is zero, it returns as `2023-02-28 16:20:25.0`.

Is there any easy way to force Postgresql to return `2023-02-28 16:20:25.000`.

Comment: You should do that in the frontend (GUI) where you _display_ those values. Formatting for the UI shouldn't be done in in SQL.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it's not for frontend display. Do you know the answer to the question or not?

Comment: Use `to_char()` to format the value in SQL.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name perfect. many thanks. Feel free to post as an answer for me to accept